# How to download image file from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, download, firebase-storage

okay so the method I have tried is .getfile() for downloading the image. it triggers onsuccess listener as well but I can't locate the file in my internal storage, not sure if I can access it

```
 @Override
    public void onDownloadClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "will try to dwonload XD" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Upload selectedItem= mUploads.get(position);
        final String selectedkey= selectedItem.getKey();
        StorageReference imgRef=mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
try{
    File localFIle=File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");

    imgRef.getFile(localFIle).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "downloaded" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("file ", "filedownloaded");


        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "not able to download" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
}
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }






    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a File object called `localFIle`.  If you want to know what path that it, just log its string value.  If that's not the location you want, try something else.  I suggest reading [the documentation on locating files on Android devices](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files).